# How to read in a http status of a request made outside of a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a Cloudfront action when a user attempts to directly access a file (say, a JPG) from the same route as our ReactJS app (eg. http:/www.app.com/view/doc1/something.jpg) - that request hits cloudfront first, and it decides wether you have the permissions or it exists and either serves it up - or throws you back to our React app.

In the browser network activity list, the request for the file is there, and returned from cloudfront with say a 403.

How do I read in that http request status on that file into the React app itself so we can handle the 403/404 etc?

We currently just match on the route with a regex, and expect that if you've landed back at the react app, that something went wrong and have a generic "You couldnt get this file" page - but we'd like to serve up based on the status code a more elegant message to the user.

The other concept was to have a landing page at this file route, and let the react app fire a preflight to see if they will be able to access the file directly - and use the status from the preflight to elegantly handle the response for the user.

Alternatively, Id like to be able to interrogate the browsers request for file x, and get its requests status code intot he React app to act upon it - or hear of any packages or ways others have done this...

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation in our project, So we wrapped axios library in our custom `HttpInterceptor` wrapper. This wrapped `HttpInterceptor` interceptors all calls made by your browser.

```
let HttpInterceptor = axios.create({
  headers: {
    Accept: "image/jpeg" 
  }
});

HttpInterceptor.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      // Redirect or Do whatever yu want to do if call fails
    }
    return response;
  },
  function(error) {
    throw error;
  }
);
export default HttpInterceptor;
```

Comment: Cool idea - but that would only catch any requests made by axios, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Just a suggestion it is always better to wrap any third party library. i.e Axios.

**Watch This** - Justin Searls – Please don't mock me - YouTube
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Af4M8GMoxi4)

Comment: Yes we have all of our in-app calls using axios - but sadly this one file call happens before cloudfront hands us over to the app - so its in the browsers network activity pane as a 403 error, but I cant seem to read that in sadly. All good - will try one of my other solutions.